# Parameter Validation on Reports

Tags: validation, reporting-services, report

I'm new to SSRS, so I apologize if this question is too simple:

I have a report which accepts a parameter called "Amount". I want to constrain valid inputs to currency values >= 0, and pop open an error message if the user enters improper values.

I don't want to validate inputs in my stored procedure and throw exceptions, because SSRS displays a very generic "Query execution failed for 'someTable'" message to users who access the report from another machine, and my business does not want to turn on the "Enable Remote Errors" flag.

**How do I add input validation to report parameters and notify users of bad input?**

Yes, I've googled around, but haven't had much luck. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, how about this?

All you have in SSRS, really, is the SQL query and expressions in report fields.

Perhaps you could add a big, red text box at the top of the report for your error message, and give it an expression like '=IIf(Parameters!Amount.Value < 0, "Error: Invalid Amount", "")'.

Then go to your table's "Hidden" property and give it the expression "=Parameters!Amount.Value < 0"

You could also add into your query's where clause and add "AND @Amount >= 0" so you aren't fetching from the database when there's an error.

Comment: In case anyone needs screenshots: [step1 - right click TextBox - Expression](http://i.imgur.com/jwyxrt9.png) [step2 - Right click tablix](http://i.imgur.com/1gmSpSt.png) [step3 - add Expression to "Visibility"](http://i.imgur.com/QQnjygh.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make report parameters in SSRS that are based on a particular list or a lookup query but I don't think you can apply a regex or something like that.

Instead you might consider separating your report into two panels, one which displays your report and one which displays an error and then you create an assembly with a function in it that validates the parameters for the report before it is run. If the validate parameters function is successful you hide the error panel and show the report panel, if not you do the opposite.

Comment: I'm not really looking for a regex solution. Also, the "two panels + custom DLL to validate error" option sounds a little overkill (not to mention the extra assembly complicates deployment) -- is this the standard way to validate report parameters?

Comment: Instead of a separate DLL it's possible to embed code in the report. I'm not sure if custom code is the standard way to validate parameters but it certainly seems like the most sensible way to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a whole lot you can do in the reporting tool itself.  It's pretty rudimentary.

However, you can provide an ASP.net web interface or a form that you can use to ask the users for the parameter values in any format .NET allows, and use the ReportViewer control to display the report.  It sounds daunting, but it's actually pretty straight-forward, particularly if you already have a project you can build on.

Microsoft gives [tutorials for using the ReportViewer controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337090.aspx).

Comment: There's no project to build on, these reports are strictly internal and our accounting dept visits the default http://someserver/Reports page that MS provides. Its a little more work than its worth to write a web interface around this site just for param validation :)